# Clone widgets and its all child in Gtk

Tags: python, c++, gtk, glade

I am using Gtk to create an application and I need to use a stack page again and again with different data on each page. I designed a page with glade but now want to clone it and use it in different pages of the stack. Please help me.

Comment: Widgets are not cloned. (I cannot remember that I ever saw it in any widget set I've used myself.) This probably might contradict with the requirement that each widget has to be unique (to ensure unique properties). Nevertheless, you can repeat the creation of "same" widgets again and again. For this, either make a function for the composed widgets creation and call it multiple times, or create even a class for your composed widget which you can instance multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

I got what I wanted to do. Basically, I wanted to use multiple widgets arranged in order to give me a template to use dynamically in my app. Composite widgets are one I was looking for. Which can be made and used with pygi ([gi_composite library in python](https://github.com/virtuald/pygi-composite-templates))